# how to call functions from different class from tornado.gen.task?

Tags: python, tornado

I know when calling tornado.gen.task the function should contain a callback parameter but how to do that when calling functions from a different class?

```
class RequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     @gen.coroutine
     def get(self, path):
         response = yield tornado.gen.Task(Query('hello').do_things())
         self.write('<h1>' + response + '</h1>')
         self.finish()


class Query:
    def __init__(self, query):
        self.query = query
        #defined some parameters

    def parsing(self):
        #do some processing

    def do_things(self):
        #do things by using all defined parameters and parsing function
        return #something
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Tornado, but from a general callback perspective, I'd expect you'd pass the bound method `Query('hello').do_things` (without the parentheses at the end!) as your callback. The code you've shown calls `do_things` before the `Task` has been created or `yield`ed, which I think is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a function to `Task` (and params if needed). So the right call should be

```
class RequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     @gen.coroutine
     def get(self, path):
         response = yield tornado.gen.Task(Query('hello').do_things)
         self.write('<h1>' + response + '</h1>')
         self.finish()
```

But the `do_things` is not a coroutine nor callback-style async function - it cloud be called just like `response = Query('hello').do_things()`.

From [Task docs](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.Task):

> Adapts a callback-based asynchronous function for use in coroutines.
>
> Takes a function (and optional additional arguments) and runs it with
>   those arguments plus a callback keyword argument. The argument passed
>   to the callback is returned as the result of the yield expression.

So your `do_things` is missing callback argument, that must be called to provide results

```
class Query:

    def do_things(self, callback):
        #do things by using all defined parameters and parsing function
        return callback(some_res)
```

And version without (explicit) callbacks, so the Task wrapper is not needed:

```
class RequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     @gen.coroutine
     def get(self, path):
         response = yield Query('hello').do_things()
         self.write('<h1>' + response + '</h1>')
         self.finish()

class Query:
    @gen.coroutine
    def do_things(self):
        #do things by using all defined parameters and parsing function
        return some_res
```

Comment: I am also calling function "parsing" in "do_things" so do i need to add @gen.coroutine there also?

Comment: Adding `gen.coroutine` makes sense if the decorated function is  asynchronous/non-blocking, as I presumed `do_things` will do.